# Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected in Auth.php

Tags: php, facebook, hybridauth

I'm currently implementing a social-accounts login function for my project in uni.

I've installed HybridAuth by composer and follow exactly the guide on HybridAuth webpage.

My code:

```
...
else if (isset($_REQUEST["provider"])) {
// the selected provider
$provider_name = $_REQUEST["provider"]; // currently testing with only Facebook provider
try {
    // initialize Hybrid_Auth class with the config file
    require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
    $config = array(
        "base_url" => 'http://localhost/project/vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/hybridauth',
        "providers" => array (
            "Facebook" => array (
                "enabled" => true,
                "keys"    => array ( "id" => "xxxxxxx", "secret" => "xxxxxxx" ),
                "display" => "popup" // optional
            )));
    $hybridauth = new Hybrid_Auth($config);

    // try to authenticate with the selected provider
    $adapter = $hybridauth->authenticate($provider_name);

    // then grab the user profile
    $user_profile = $adapter->getUserProfile();
    echo $user_profile->displayName;
}
(Exception $e) {
....}
...
```

But then I got this error and it does not redirect me to the Facebook authentication page:

[image]

Line 367 in Auth.php:

```
if ($mode == "PHP") {header("Location: $url");}
```

Any pointers?

Comment: There's probably a new line character in `$url`.

Comment: is that the issue in my code or HybridAuth library? I've got the same thinking but not sure how to fix that.

Comment: No idea, track down how it gets set.